# Two Threads accessing a queue through synchronized methods; Can one have strict priority over the other?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to make a chat application for the network in my college. It's actually two programs: One for the server and the other for the clients. All client messages will be sent to server with their sender's name and intended target prepended to them. The server, using this information, sends the message to the target.

I wrote a program which simulates the server side of things with 4 classes: Model, MessageCentre, Receiver and Sender.

Receiver, on an independent thread, generates strings and adds them to the queue in MessageCentre with random time-outs. Sender checks if queue is empty, and if not, it 'sends' the message (just prints it).The Model class simply contains the main method which starts the Receiver and Sender threads.

This is the code of the simulation:

Model class->

```
package model;

public class Model {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Receiver receiver = new Receiver();
        Sender sender = new Sender();
        receiver.start();
        sender.start();
    }
}
```

MessageCentre class->

```
package model;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class MessageCentre {
    private static Queue<String> pendingMessages = new LinkedList<>();

    public static synchronized boolean centreIsEmpty() {
        return pendingMessages.isEmpty();
    }

    public static synchronized String readNextAndRemove() {
        return pendingMessages.remove();
    }

    public static synchronized boolean addToQueue(String message) {
        return pendingMessages.add(message);
    }
}
```

Receiver class->

```
package model;

import java.util.Random;

public class Receiver extends Thread {

    private int instance;

    public Receiver() {
        instance = 0; //gets incremented after each message
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {            
            boolean added = MessageCentre.addToQueue(getMessage());
            if (!added) {
                System.out.println("Message " + instance + " failed to send");
            }
            try {
                //don't send for another 0 to 10 seconds
                Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(10_000));                
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private String getMessage() {
        int copyInstance = instance;
        instance++;

        return "Message " + copyInstance;
    }
}
```

Sender class->

```
package model;

public class Sender extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            if(!MessageCentre.centreIsEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(MessageCentre.readNextAndRemove());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Question: If the `getMessage()` method of the Receiver class were to be replaced by a method which accepts messages from a socket input stream, is there a chance that some messages would be lost?

It is crucial that all received messages be written to the queue so that no messages are lost. This simulation seems to run fine, but I have no way to test a scenario where a large influx of messages are being received through a socket.

The case which I fear might occur is the following:

Receiver gets a message and attempts to write it to the queue.
Sender has a hold of the queue to read and remove items from it, thereby preventing Receiver from writing the newest message. The Receiver finally gets the opportunity to write the current message to the queue, but a new message simultaneously enters the socket input stream to be lost forever.

Is this scenario possible? If so, can it be prevented by setting the priority level of Receiver to be higher than Sender?

Comment: The socket should buffer, this wouldnt be a problem. There is no way to express priority in terms of synchro, the closest is thread priority but this is just a hint to the OS

Comment: @Neil Locketz Yes, the buffer is essential, but even it has its limits. I thought this is precisely the function of the queue; Add pending messages to the queue immediately, but treat the sending of them to the targets a secondary matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a new message simultaneously enters the socket input stream to be lost forever

is always possible, but large numbers of dropped requests are unlikely unless you're under heavy load or have unnecessarily large critical sections.  Dropped requests also happen due to factors outside your control, so your system needs to be robust in the face of them anyway.

Use [a queue implementation from `java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) instead of manually synchronizing on a `LinkedList` and the queue portion of your code should be fine.

Comment: The college is populated by 200-some people. If the vast majority of these folks were to be chatting back 'n' forth, would this constitute 'heavy load'? Also, would it be beneficial to split the traffic into multiple ports with independent threads listening to reduce the chance of message loss?

Comment: No.  It depends on your hardware and the efficiency of your design & implementation, but 200 persistent simultaneous connections is not a lot.  [This benchmark](http://bocoup.com/weblog/node-stress-test-analysis/) doesn't show problems until it gets above 17k connections.